# Auto-collapse OpenUI5 Side Navigation on mobile

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I've got an application which looks very much like this example
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.tnt.sample.ToolPage/preview

The SideNavigation is great, but I wonder if there's an official way to auto-collapse it on a smartphone.

I know how to listen to a resize even using vanilla JS or jQuery. I could easily add that functionality, but I'm looking for a more OpenUI5 like way to achieve that as I expect to have more similar requirements.

Can I bind such a property to a screen size? I know that the SplitApp container does that, but I'd like to use my SideNavigation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

ToolPage has a property called `sideExpanded`. If you put the side navigation to this container (it's recommended), you can control this property by a boolean.

You can bind this property to a model attribute, or even to the Device model (`{device>/system/phone}`).

Example:

`<tnt:ToolPage id="toolPage" sideExpanded="{device>/system/phone}">
...
</tnt:ToolPage>`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the elegance I was looking for! I'm a bit surprised that my super small browser windows on a desktop is still considered as a desktop though.
I've used `<tnt:SideNavigation id="sideNavigation" expanded="{device>/system/phone}">` since I want to keep the icons and only hide the text on the phone.

Comment: Yes, because it's not a responsive feature yet, it just checks the device type. If you set Chrome to emulate a phone (using F12 Dev. Tools), the sidebar should be collapsed.